# How to start a java service from Jenkins

Tags: java, spring-boot, jenkins, continuous-deployment

Jenkins newbie here, I'm using Jenkins to build a SpringBoot app with Maven. What I have done ok so far:

1. Check out the code
2. Build the app
3. Copy the app to app folder.

However i could not complete this step:

4. Start the app as a server (standalone, not using Tomcat).
   I use this command

`java -jar app.jar &`

but as long as Jenkins finishs the job, the app also quits (I don't see the log shows that the app exits, but when I checked, it did not run)
Jenkins runs on same server with the app (Amazon linux).
Any help is much appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `nohup`. Something like this:

```
killall -9 app.jar
nohup java -jar app.jar > app.log 2>&1 &
```

But I strongly advise you to create a Docker image with your application to deploy it.

Best regards.

Comment: Can you plz share a tutorial on how to do it with docker? Thank you.

Comment: still does not work, however i will deploy with docker as you advised. Thanks